# Libgdx crash on dispose()?

Tags: java, libgdx, memory-efficiency

Whenever I try to manually call the dispose method in one of my screen my game just crashes.

My dispose looks something like this

```
@Override
public void dispose() {
    battletheme.dispose();
    renderer.dispose();
    bg.dispose();
    enemy.dispose();
    dialouge.dispose();
    GameTools.fontText.dispose();
}
```

and I use

```
this.dispose();
```

When I switch to another screen, otherwise my memory begins to pile up. Is there any reason for this?

EDIT: My spritebatch called "renderer" seems to crash on dispose, any reason?

Comment: Can you show the exception thrown when it crashes?

Comment: The crash is probably because you used the function to call itself, with infinite recursion.  You're probably looking for `super.dispose()`

Answer (score 1):

The `dispose()` function is made to be called at the end of the program's life cycle. You calling `renderer.dispose()` is manually garbage-collecting the `renderer` and this most likely works by setting it to `null` which will, in turn, cause the JVM to respond by destroying the object. You are probably trying to re-access the `renderer` object after it's destruction and failing by causing a `NullPointerException` which is produced when a variable contains a `null` value due to the fact that you can't use `null` to do anything as `null` means nothing :)

Hope this helps! ~ Ammar Tarajia